# Set QuickContactBadge image to contact's profile picture

Tags: android, android-layout, contactscontract, quickcontactbadge

I'm using a QuickContactBadge and want it to display the contact's profile picture.
This is how I'm loading the contact info:

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactId));
    QuickContactBadge badge = (QuickContactBadge) findViewById(R.id.badge);
    badge.setMode(ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_LARGE);
    badge.assignContactUri(contactUri);
```

What would be the simplest way? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(), contactUri);
badge.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input));
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get the facebook profile picture in the badge? I'm getting the error isQmage : stream is not a Qmage file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manage the bitmap yourself. Just take the photoUri from the ContactsContract.Contacts content provider (the same where you get the contactId)

```
Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI))
badge.setImageURI(photoUri)
```